# Express handle CPU heavy request

Tags: node.js

ALl:

I am pretty new to Node and Express, I wonder if anyone could give me a little explain how Express server works when handle the request, I got server stuck when make some CPU calc heavy request, for an simple example:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    // some long time math calculation in for loop or while to get data
    res.json(data);
})
```

I thought Node is event loop based single process, when a task fired, the task will be put into a thread pool, and this single process keep asking if it finish or not, for my example, I thought app.get can put the handler function task in that pool and waiting for other request, but unfortuantely it does not seems work in that way.

So how exactly it works in app.get and how can I seperate this heavy calc task and make this request handler waiting for other request?

Any example will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: don't do heavy calculation in main thread, use node cluster!

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS, like browser JavaScript, is single-threaded. Tasks to be executed (such as your handler function) are put in the event queue, and executed in sequence. Therefore, if one function is taking a long time to execute, it will prevent other stuff in the queue (such as another request) from running.

If you don't want your long computation to prevent other requests from being processed, you can split it up across multiple times through the event loop, e.g. with `setImmediate()`. See [this page on the NodeJS event loop](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/topics/the-event-loop-timers-and-nexttick.md).

A (probably better) option would be to do the computation in another thread/process, so that it doesn't interfere with request handling at all.

Comment: Another option is to delegate CPU-intensive operations to another process. The event loop will not block while waiting for the outcome of a remote operation.

Comment: Beats me, I didn't downvote. But I must admit that the question itself isn't of very good quality (and it doesn't show much effort), which in turn may attract people retaliating its answers with downvotes. I honestly can't think of an improvement to this answer other than showing concrete examples (perhaps in Express using the `child_process` module), but I can hardly believe it's worth the effort right now.